# How to avoid empty rows after actual data by using PHPExcel

Tags: mysql, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for importing data to the mysql database.

My code is,

```
require APPPATH . 'phpexcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['ifile']['tmp_name']);
$data = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

In my excel sheet having 14 rows,but `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow()` returns 1047856 rows. Due to this the processing time too high. So `$data` returns error and server gets slow. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

No, your Excel sheet has something in those rows: whether data or styling or print settings or whatever, they exist in the excel file itself.... however, there is a `getHighestDataRow()` method that looks at the actual content of cells rather than simply their existence in a file. It will still return cells that contain a NULL or an empty string, but is probably better for your use.

If `getHighestDataRow()` resolved your problem with the row count, then you should probably also consider using `rangeToArray()` rather than `toArray()`

Comment: While I am using getHighestDataRow() shows error like "ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::getHighestDataRow()"

Comment: Individual worksheets have rows, not the top level Excel object..... `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestDataRow()`

Comment: Using last version of PHPExcel but getHighestDataRow() function is undefined

Comment: [Doesn't look undefined to me](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php#L1060) What error are you getting?

Comment: @MarkBaker : i have deleted 32 out of 33 rows from excel file and uploaded again. Still $sheet->getHighestDataRow() function returns '33' as count.